# Font blocked by CORS policy-subdomain

Tags: html, .htaccess, fonts, icons

I have my main site (website.com) and a sub domain (fancy.website.com), however I am getting

```
Access to font at 'social icons souce' from origin 'fancy.website.com'
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource.
```

I made sure that both of the sites are using HTTPS, and my htaccess looks like this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *.website.com

<FilesMatch "\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

here is what it looks like on my website.com [icons showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ks6o.png) and on fancy.website.com [broken icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JedY.png)
I've cleared my caches, and the social icons the sub domain is  trying to get show up on the main website. What can I do next to get them to show up?

Comment: I think you have to tell the web server to accept x-origin requests.  I do not know if `.htaccess` changes are enough for this.  what kind of server are you using? (i.e. apache, node, tomcat, etc.)

Comment: plesk which uses apache

Comment: have you tried something like this: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001338265-How-to-set-up-CORS-cross-origin-resource-sharing-in-Plesk-

Comment: I did that and it still doesn't work

Comment: I am afraid there is not enough information in your question at this point. We could be guessing all day long.  Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to try to improve it.  Great questions get quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: Okay, what information would be helpful?

Comment: how are you making the x-origin request ? do you see anything in the logs? are you *sure* the `.htaccess` file is loaded correctly? (i.e. no syntax errors) is the plesk server also reading the new headers correctly? (no restart necessary?)